# Flutter opacity on image within container

Tags: image, flutter, dart, opacity

I couldn't find a way to make this image within a container opaque.

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 12, horizontal: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("images/img.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown),
      ),
      child: SomeWidget(),
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `DecorationImage` and it has a method `colorFilter` you can use it for the opacity

Here is the sample how I am using it in my code.

```
colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
```

And you can also use [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html)

Comment: That just creates a big block of opaque colour on top of the image...? Also there is no need to use `new` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a container's decoration section, just like sunny's answer above but instead of `Colors.black`
use `Colors.white`:

```
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                    image: new AssetImage("assets/images/tankicon.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
                  )),
                  child:
```